# CSS Border Wrap Around Effect with Delay & Transitions

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to recreate the border effect exactly that is on "Quote of the Day" here:

https://www.forbes.com/ (please scroll down the page)

So it is delayed and wraps around.

https://jsfiddle.net/benchesters/w8djLcb7/3/

The problem is I cannot get any of the animations working and I have no idea why, despite using the same html and css.

```
.qotd-section.animated-borders .border-top-1,.qotd-section.animated-borders .border-top-2{
    -webkit-transition-delay:0s;
    -o-transition-delay:0s;
    transition-delay:0s
}
.qotd-section.animated-borders .border-left,.qotd-section.animated-borders .border-right{
    -webkit-transition-delay:.7s;
    -o-transition-delay:.7s;
    transition-delay:.7s
}
.qotd-section.animated-borders .border-bottom-1,.qotd-section.animated-borders .border-bottom-2{
    -webkit-transition-delay:1.4s;
```

Comment: Your code is not changing any of the dimensions that your are transitioning. I guess the original has some action which triggers a change in width etc. For example an onload event or an IntersectionObserver or some scroll JS code. Just to give an opinion - it's not great having all that essentially visual design stuff needing all those extra elements which don't have any actual meaning to them. I'd try to do the whole thing with styling ie in CSS instead to separate things out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*this seems like a very basic question, make sure you understand the basics, a good resource is [w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) tutorial on css transitions*

## Css transition

There's a lot of different ways to animate something. This particular animation is using css transitions.
Basically a transition specifies how an element will go from 1 state to another.

State in this case are the applied css rules. The applied css rules will change once a class is applied. in this case it's `animated-borders`.

in the example below i've added an button to add or remove the `animated-borders` class from the `qotd-section` element.
You'll see the animation play whenever the `animated-borders` class is applied.
On their own page, they are likely adding this class when the element scrolls into view. See [w3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asp) scoll events for examples on that.

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('.toggle-class');

btn.onclick = function() {
  var el = document.querySelector('.qotd-section');
  el.classList.toggle('animated-borders');
}
```

```css
.qotd-section {
  padding: 25px 100px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center
}

.qotd-section .animated-border__horizontal {
  background-color: #ece5c0;
  height: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0
}

.qotd-section .animated-border__vertical {
  background-color: #ece5c0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 8px
}

.qotd-section .border-left {
  left: 0
}

.qotd-section .border-right {
  right: 0
}

.qotd-section .border-top-1 {
  margin-left: calc(50% - 100px);
  top: 0;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%)
}

.qotd-section .border-top-2 {
  left: 50%;
  top: 0
}

.qotd-section .border-bottom-1 {
  bottom: 0;
  margin-left: calc(100% - 100px);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%)
}

.qotd-section .border-bottom-2 {
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0
}

.qotd-section.animated-borders .animated-border__horizontal {
  -webkit-transition: width .7s ease-in;
  -o-transition: width .7s ease-in;
  transition: width .7s ease-in;
  width: 50%
}

.qotd-section.animated-borders .animated-border__vertical {
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: height .7s ease-in;
  -o-transition: height .7s ease-in;
  transition: height .7s ease-in
}

.qotd-section.animated-borders .border-top-1,
.qotd-section.animated-borders .border-top-2 {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  -o-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s
}

.qotd-section.animated-borders .border-left,
.qotd-section.animated-borders .border-right {
  -webkit-transition-delay: .7s;
  -o-transition-delay: .7s;
  transition-delay: .7s
}

.qotd-section.animated-borders .border-bottom-1,
.qotd-section.animated-borders .border-bottom-2 {
  -webkit-transition-delay: 1.4s;
  -o-transition-delay: 1.4s;
  transition-delay: 1.4s
}

.qotd-section__label {
  background-color: #fcfcfc;
  color: #737373;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  padding: 0 20px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  top: 4px;
  -webkit-transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1
}

.qotd-section__description {
  font: 700 18px Merriweather, serif;
  opacity: 0
}

.qotd-section__author,
.qotd-share__container {
  opacity: 0
}

.qotd-section__byline-author {
  font: 700 15px Merriweather, serif
}

.qotd-section__byline-title {
  font-size: 13px
}

.qotd-section.animated-borders .qotd-section__author,
.qotd-section.animated-borders .qotd-section__description {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .7s cubic-bezier(.6, -.28, .735, .045);
  -o-transition: opacity .7s cubic-bezier(.6, -.28, .735, .045);
  transition: opacity .7s cubic-bezier(.6, -.28, .735, .045)
}

.qotd-section.animated-borders .qotd-section__author {
  -webkit-transition-delay: .7s;
  -o-transition-delay: .7s;
  transition-delay: .7s
}

.qotd-section.animated-borders .qotd-share__container {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .7s cubic-bezier(.6, -.28, .735, .045);
  -o-transition: opacity .7s cubic-bezier(.6, -.28, .735, .045);
  transition: opacity .7s cubic-bezier(.6, -.28, .735, .045);
  -webkit-transition-delay: 1.4s;
  -o-transition-delay: 1.4s;
  transition-delay: 1.4s
}

@media (min-width:769px) {
  .qotd-section:hover .social-share__arrow {
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-28px);
    -ms-transform: translateX(-28px);
    transform: translateX(-28px)
  }
  .qotd-section:hover .qotd-share__icons {
    -webkit-transition: all .2s ease .2s;
    -o-transition: all .2s ease .2s;
    transition: all .2s ease .2s
  }
  .qotd-section:hover .qotd-share__icons a {
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1
  }
  .qotd-section:hover .social-share__icon-wrapper {
    position: static;
    z-index: 1
  }
  .qotd-section:hover .qotd-share__text {
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: -1
  }
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
  .qotd-wrapper {
    background: #fff;
    margin: -24px 0 0;
    padding: 25px 15px
  }
  .qotd-section {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 25px 45px
  }
  .qotd-section .border-top-1 {
    margin-left: calc(50% - 45px)
  }
  .qotd-section .border-bottom-1 {
    margin-left: calc(100% - 45px)
  }
  .qotd-section .qotd-share__icons {
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    justify-content: center;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    -ms-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0)
  }
  .qotd-section .qotd-share__icons a {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: 2;
    -ms-flex-order: 1;
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-order: 1;
    order: 1;
    z-index: 1
  }
  .qotd-section__label {
    background-color: #fff
  }
  .qotd-section__description {
    font-size: 14px
  }
  .qotd-share__container {
    width: auto
  }
  .qotd-share .qotd-share__text,
  .qotd-share .social-share__arrow {
    display: none
  }
  .social-share__icon-wrapper {
    z-index: 1
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="toggle-class">
  toggle class
</button>
<div class="qotd-wrapper">
  <div class="qotd-section fs-content ">
    <div class="animated-border__horizontal border-top-1"></div>
    <div class="animated-border__horizontal border-top-2"></div>
    <div class="animated-border__vertical border-left"></div>
    <div class="animated-border__vertical border-right"></div>
    <div class="animated-border__horizontal border-bottom-1"></div>
    <div class="animated-border__horizontal border-bottom-2"></div><span class="qotd-section__label">QUOTE OF THE DAY</span>
    <p class="qotd-section__description">“I think at the beginning of every revolution, there’s this opening of a wound.”</p>
    <p class="qotd-section__author"><span class="qotd-section__byline-author">Charlize Theron</span><span class="qotd-section__byline-title">, Actress</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```